# Is measure theory unnecessary for statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

I actually got into an argument once with a professor of statistics at a top statistics program who thought that measure theory was unnecessary to know for statistics, even for theoreticians, because all of the technical difficulties with point processes have been resolved already.

Elsewhere I have heard that some statisticians claim that measure theory "kills your intuition". (Which doesn't make sense, because when explained correctly measure theory is *very* intuitive.)

And of course the vast majority of "graduate-level" textbooks in statistics don't require or use any measure theory at all, even those which are considered "theoretical" (e.g. Berger and Casella).

Is this attitude really prevalent in the statistics community? Can anyone who thinks this way explain their reasoning to me?

Comment: Do you really mean to imply, as suggested in the first paragraph, that statistics is wholly--and only--about *point processes*?

Comment: Specify what you mean by "unnecessary", or give an example of a statistical problem what can't be solved without using measure theory.

Comment: @Kostia Well you need measure theory to explain and justify the Central Limit Theorem and hence most statistical procedures; without it they would just be wrong. And presumably you would again need to appeal to measure theory to justify the correctness (and what you mean by "correct") of your statistical tests.

Comment: @whuber Their argument was essentially: "the only time measure theory has ever been needed in the theory of statistics is to clarify the theory of point processes, and since that has already been done, there is no reason why most people studying statistical theory need to know or understand measure theory". In other words point processes was the only part of statistics for which they thought measure theory _might_ have been necessary in the past.

Comment: @William I meant to add this to your question to make it less opinion-based. To explain CLT, you don't need measure theory. To prove CLT, you do need measure theory, but I would consider this as a part of probability theory, not statistics per se.

Comment: @Kostia Fair enough, but you can't really do statistics without probability?

Comment: @William Sure. But I we can continue this chain: I can't do probability without calculus, can't do calculus without understanding arithmetics, etc.

Comment: Well Casella and Berger don't use measure theory directly but it is always in the background. It jumps in once you consider more advanced material, e.g. Lehmann's books Theory of Point Estimation and Testing Statistical hypotheses.

Comment: @JohnK Thank you for the good recommendations! I had only known of Schervish's book before

Comment: Sounds like a good topic for the [chat]. With regard to '*I have heard that some statisticians claim that measure theory "kills your intuition"* ' you say that measure theory is intuitive but that's not the point being made there. The claim is it kills your *statistical* intuition, not that measure theory itself is unintuitive on its own terms. (I am not saying I agree with it, by the way; I really don't know).

Comment: One can certainly do quite a lot without measure theory (Kendall&Stuart, Feller, Casella&Berger, Cox&Hinkley) -- and there are many excellent statisticians who don't know any of it. But I think for a theoretician you're eventually either going to need measure theory or replace it with something at least as powerful. It's quite clear that it makes many otherwise relatively difficult things simple, even obvious, and if you seek rigor and generality you need *some* tool that can provide it, so there's clearly a big benefit in doing so.

Comment: @Glen_b how do you move this conversation to chat? Also which of Feller's books are you referring to? If you're talking about introduction to probability theory and applications, vols. I and II, I think that serves more as an argument in favor of measure theory, because quite frankly the books stop making sense fairly rapidly since way too much is pushed under the rug. The section on Markov processes for example, is just a catastrophe (in my opinion).

Comment: Well, a moderator can "move the conversation" to its own chat room, but given the main chat room ([Ten Fold](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold)) is fairly quiet anyway, my thinking was simply to raise the topic there. [If you want the current conversation moved to chat, I'm happy to do it, but it may not get much attention.]

Comment: I was referring to the two volumes you mentioned by the way.